# Laravel get Many to Many count in range

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to filter all my users who ordered amount of orders in range so

```
User::where('type','client')
->whereHas('orders',function ($query) use($min_orders,$max_orders){

})
```

any solution??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `has()` filter to filter out users with min and max count of associated orders

```
User::where('type','client')
    ->has('orders', '>=', $min_orders)
    ->has('orders', '<=', $max_orders)
    ->get()
```

[See Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Great it works but what if I want to sum the total of order to filter it any clue !?

Comment: @user10076385 You might ask it as a separate question , I will try to answer it there.